# Ajax Remember selected options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my DB I have tables `System(id, name)` and `AssignedSystems(id, system_id)`. I display every system from the second table like this (I can't copy my code, so I have to rewrite it, I will use pseudo PHP+HTML):

```
while () { // if there are many systems assigned, I will display them all in separate selects
<select><option value="'.$systemAssigned.'">'.$systemAssigned.'</option>
    while () {
        // display every system from table System except for the one listed above
    }
    </select><img src="drop.gif" onclick="deleteSystem()">
} 
<img src="plus.gif" onclick="addSelect()">
```

JavaScript (to be specfic - AJAX) functions `deleteSystem()` and `addSelect()` do (in order) delete a row from `AssignedSystems` and add new select, so a new system can be selected from table `System`.

Now when I want to add few, let's say 3 new selects, I have to click `plus.gif` three times - and the page reloads three times with a new select added. Now I would like to have my previous selections remembered. So when I click `plus.gif` one time and select a system, then click `plus.gif` again and again I would like to have my first selection remembered.

I thought about using sessions variables like:

```
<select>
$_SESSION["selectValue"] = SELECTED_VALUE_WHEN_PLUS.GIF_IS_CLICKED;
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

or passing the currently selected value to javascript, but I don't really know how, because I don't have any specific number of blank selects, so I don't know how to retrieve it back.

Comment: If your `addSelect()` function is truly AJAX, the page should not be reloading. It's the page reload that's causing the DOM to refresh and your previously selected items to be "forgotten".

Comment: Well, as an argument of `addSelect()` I pass a number to be looped through to print my selects.

Comment: You're going to have to show a lot more code to get this solved. Particularly the `addSelect()` function. Off of the top of my head, however, I could suggest that you build a global array of your previously 'added' items in Javascript at each call of the `addSelect()` function.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really want to write everything here, because I've got a lot of it and I can't copy it right away. I will try with the array though. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, so I use an array to store each selected value. Thanks for your suggestion, I'm surprised I didn't come up with this.